# Floor equation with square roots

Tags: functions, radicals, ceiling-and-floor-functions, sums-of-squares

> Find the smallest positive integer $n$ that satisfies
>   $$\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor = \lfloor \sqrt{n + 34} \rfloor$$

Comment: $17^2$ fits ${}$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to see when the difference between two squares is equal to 34.  $17^2-16^2=289-256=33$ and $18^2-17^2=324-289=35$. Therefore n should be around $289$, and check it by plugging it in:
$\lfloor{289}\rfloor=\lfloor{323}\rfloor$ and $324=18^2$ so $\boxed{289}$ is valid.